# Array to Stack in java , and remove operators

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I have one array (25*ax+c-d/2) and i want to put everything in a stack and next remove the operators ( *;+;-;/) and have at the end (25;ax;c;d) in a stack implementation.

Right now i have :

```js
import java.util.*; 
  
public class StackDemo { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
       //Creating array
       ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
      
       //Adding to array
       al.add("25*ax+c-d/2");
      
       
       //Creating a stack 
        Stack<String> STACK = new Stack<String>(); 
  
        //Adding array to stack 
        for(String str : al)
     STACK.add(str);
  
        // Displaying the Stack 
        System.out.println("Initial Stack: " + STACK); 
  
    } 
}
```

I know I'm grouping everything in the same stack position, but how can I separate and then remove the operators?

Comment: Your solution is pretty far away from being functional.  As a hint, you can start by writing some logic which can identify one or more _tokens_ which might appear in your algebraic expression.  Here, a token means for example a number (e.g. `25`) or an operator (e.g. `+` or `-`).  Then, your code needs to read each token, one at a time, and figure out what to do with them, by putting them on the stack, or doing a math operation.

Comment: i dont need to a math operation , i just need to remove the operators of the array and put the result on different positions of the stack.

Comment: Why? Hard to see the utility of this. Surely at some point you are going to evaluate the expression? Don't design the solution before you fully understand the problem. Hint: Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to split the expression with operators:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creating array
    List<String> al = Arrays.asList("25*ax+c-d/2".split("[\\*+/-]"));

    //Creating a stack 
    Stack<String> STACK = new Stack<String>(); 

    //Adding array to stack 
    for(String str : al)
        STACK.add(str);

    // Displaying the Stack 
    System.out.println("Initial Stack: " + STACK); 
}
```

Output:

```
Initial Stack: [25, ax, c, d, 2]
```

Comment: The only thing you need to escape here is `*`.

Comment: You're right, it should be "[\\*+/-]", i'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDoc reference of `Stack` class:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

```java
Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>();
```

In your scenario, it is possible to initialize a `Deque` by passing an `ArrayList` directly:

```java
List<String> al = Arrays.asList("25*ax+c-d/2".split("[\\*+/-]"));
Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>(al);
```